# how to make factorization by a group action

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

any algebra and numerical example for Projectivization

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectivization

which book or paper teaching this

Comment: Look for Grassmannian manifolds. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a group $G$ act on a set $X$. We identify two elements, $x,y$ of $X$ in the quotient set iff they are on the same orbit, i.e. there is $g\in G:\ gx=y$.

In the given example of projectivization,

> The projective space $\Bbb P(V)$ is the quotient of the open set $V\setminus\{0\}$ of nonzero vectors by the action of the multiplicative group of the base field by scalar transformations.

In other words, as the multiplicative group of scalars contains the nonzero scalars, two vectors $v,w\in V\setminus\{0\}$ represent the same element in $\Bbb P(V)$ iff $\lambda\cdot v=w$ for some $\lambda\ne 0$ scalar.

Comment: i know this definition, expect an example in Maple